# Extracting a word from the line in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following lines,

```
<property id_type="Sabre TripCase - Mobile" modification_timestamp="2015-10-07T09:47:15.0Z" property_id="000002" media_listing_url="/1098828.xml" property_name="WESTIN BAYSHORE VANCOUVER" address_line1="1601 Bayshore Drive" address_line2="" city="Vancouver" state="BC" zip="V6g 2V4" country="Canada" phone="1-604-682-3377" latitude="" longitude="richMediaUrl="http://www.vfmii.com/exc/aspquery?command=invoke&amp;ipid=000002&amp;ids=96102">

<property id_type="Sabre TripCase - Mobile" modification_timestamp="2016-03-10T09:15:50.0Z" property_id="000004" media_listing_url="/1105855.xml" property_name="SWISSOTEL THE STAMFORD" address_line1="2 STAMFORD ROAD" address_line2="" city="Singapore" state="" zip="178882" country="Singapore" phone="65-6338-8585" latitude="" longitude="richMediaUrl="http://www.vfmii.com/exc/aspquery?command=invoke&amp;ipid=000004&amp;ids=96102">"
```

I need command in shell ,which will extract out and give the values like,

000002,1098828
000004,1105855

I tried with sed,egrep but everything giving me entire line.
Regards,
Ragavan

@Tom Your fix is working tom except at some negative scenarios,

```
<property id_type="Sabre TripCase - Mobile" modification_timestamp="2016-03-10T09:15:50.0Z" property_id="000004" media_listing_url="/1105855.xml" property_name="SWISSOTEL THE STAMFORD" address_line1="2 STAMFORD ROAD" address_line2="" city="Singapore" state="" zip="178882" country="Singapore" phone="65-6338-8585" latitude="" longitude="richMediaUrl="http://www.vfmii.com/exc/aspquery?command=invoke&amp;ipid=000004&amp;ids=96102">"

<property id_type="Sabre TripCase - Mobile" modification_timestamp="2016-03-10T09:15:50.0Z" property_id="000005"  property_name="SWISSOTEL THE STAMFORD" address_line1="2 STAMFORD ROAD" address_line2="" city="Singapore" state="" zip="178882" country="Singapore" phone="65-6338-8585" latitude="" longitude="richMediaUrl="http://www.vfmii.com/exc/aspquery?command=invoke&amp;ipid=000004&amp;ids=96104">"

<property id_type="Sabre TripCase - Mobile" modification_timestamp="2016-03-10T09:15:50.0Z"  media_listing_url="/1105856.xml" property_name="SWISSOTEL THE STAMFORD" address_line1="2 STAMFORD ROAD" address_line2="" city="Singapore" state="" zip="178882" country="Singapore" phone="65-6338-8585" latitude="" longitude="richMediaUrl="http://www.vfmii.com/exc/aspquery?command=invoke&amp;ipid=000004&amp;ids=96104">"
```

i need to print it like,
000001,1066545
000005,
,1105856

Regards,
Ragavan

Comment: Parsing XML using BASH tools isn't advisable

Comment: Thanks anubhava, it's not xml file,it's a text file containing some date from xml,

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it removed the original question. You can use a code block to show us your XML (select the text and type Ctrl-k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not particularly flexible but this works for the data you've shown:

```
sed -E 's/.*property_id="([0-9]+)".*media_listing_url="[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1,\2/' file
```

Use sed to capture the parts you're interested in (the numbers in each property value) and use them in the replacement string, separated by a comma.

Given your more complex requirement, I'd recommend using something like this (requires GNU awk):

```
awk '{ match($0, /property_id="([0-9]+)"/, id); 
    match($0, /media_listing_url="[^0-9]*([0-9]+)/, url); 
    print id[1] "," url[1] }' file
```

The third argument to `match` specifies an array, which is cleared when there are no matches and populated with the captured groups when there are.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom,This is working absolutely fine.But in one scenario, say if   media_listing_url was not present in the line,instead of printing blank it's printing entire line. For the below string,                                                              
< property_id="000002" property_name="WESTIN BAYSHORE VANCOUVER" address_line1="1601 Bayshore Drive">                            It's printing entire line.

Comment: Like I said, it's not very flexible! Please edit your question to show a better example of your input, then maybe I can adjust my answer.

Comment: Use the edit link beneath your question to post some better input, not the comments.

Comment: @Raghavan I've added an option that you may be able to use, depending on your version of awk.

Comment: Sorry Tom,Gotta data-center activities unable to see your post.It works completely fine for me.Thanks a TON TOM !!!

Answer (score 0):

Pure awk solution

#### 1. A simple delimiter based parsing.

```
awk -F'"' '{print $6 "," $8}' file.txt | awk -F/ '{print $1 $2}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'
```

Your input data should be in **file.txt** .

#### 2. awk with gsub

```
awk -F'"' '{gsub(".xml","");gsub("/",""); print $6 "," $8}' file.txt
```

#### 3. perl solution

Extracting property Id's

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 \n" if /(?<=property_id=\")(.+?)(?=\")/' <file.txt >file1.txt
```

Result:

```
000002
000004
```

Extracting media_listing_url

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 \n" if /(?<=media_listing_url=\"\/)(.+?)(?=\.)/' <file.txt >file2.txt
```

Result:

```
1098828
1105855
```

Now joining both values :-

```
paste -d, file1.txt file2.txt
```

Result:

```
000002,1098828
000004,1105855
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried egrep with -o argument ?

Comment: I tried grep -E but it's giving entire line,not specifc String.I tried with sed with an option of extracting between quotes,sadly it's not paying off

Comment: @Raghavan: A.Durand said `egrep -o`, not `grep -E`.